# how to use append() in c?

Tags: c, append

I'm trying to add the index of a value, if it is ==1, to a list in C. Is this even possible? How would I go about it?

this is the general code I have so far:

```
int ones[256];
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < sizeof(input); i++) {
        if (input & 1 == 1) {
            
            count = count + 1;
        
            ones.append() = index;
        }
```

Comment: There is no `append` in C. (And in your code there is no list present.) If you want to store a value in an array, you must assign it to the correct index yourself. If you want to increase the size of the array, that is not possible at all with normal arrays. You need dynamic memory allocation for that.

Comment: What's `append()`?  Are you sure you tagged the right language?

Comment: That if tests if `input`, whatever it is, is odd, not if it's 1.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement append yourself. You probably want to wrap that implementation using an array struct that tracks both the length and the elements (optionally you can track capacity and over-allocate). A basic mockup looks like [this](https://www.godbolt.org/z/6Er7hdzaq):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void append(int** array, size_t* length, int element) {
    *array = (int*) realloc(*array, 1 + *length);
    (*array)[*length] = element;
    *length += 1;
}

void print(int* array, size_t len) {
    printf("Array(%lu): ", len);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int* array = (int*)malloc(0);
    size_t len = 0;
    print(array, len);
    append(&array, &len, 0);
    append(&array, &len, 1);
    append(&array, &len, 2);
    print(array, len);
}
```